# Smart algorithm to create unique exponential sequence steps between two values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm

I'm looking for a algorithm that returns 5 steps between 2 given dynamic values, including both starting values, with exponential growth. The returned values should be nicely rounded and unique.

Example:
range **100 - 10000** should return something like this:

```
100, 500, 2500, 5000, 10000
```

This is what i came up with so far (credit goes mostly to the SO thread I once found but can't recover):

```
min = 100
max = 10000
a = Array.new
loops = 5
factor = 2.5

for i in 0..loops-1
  x = (max - min) * ( (i.to_f / (loops.to_f - 1.0)) ** factor ) + min
  case x
  when min
    a[i] = x.to_i
  when max
    a[i] = x.to_i
  when (min + 1).to_f..500
    a[i] = (x.to_f / 250).round(0) * 250
  when 500..2000
    a[i] = (x.to_f / 500).round(0) * 500
  else
    a[i] = (x.to_f / 2500).round(0) * 2500
  end
end
```

The result is adjustable with the factor, I found 2.5 to be working best. This works quite well already in most cases. Before rounding I get these values:

```
[100.0, 409.37, 1850.08, 4922.67, 10000.0]
```

But it does not check for duplicates that can occur in the rounding process, which happens mostly if the range is smaller:

```
100 - 1000
Raw: [100.0, 128.12, 259.09, 538.42, 1000.0]
Rounded: [100, 250, 250, 500, 1000]
5000 - 10000
Raw: [5000.0, 5156.25,5883.88, 7435.69, 10000.0]
Rounded: [5000, 5000, 5000, 7500, 10000]
```

Now I'm a little torn between discarding the whole code and trying to come up with a smarter calculation method that already includes rounding or just checking for duplicates on a second run - but I didn't get a satisfying result from any of those two options.

Does someone have a clue on how to integrate a duplicate check in the rounding or make the rounding more dynamic?

Comment: It is not clear what your real requirements are. Your first example is *not* exponential growth, and if you want intermediate rounded values between two ends arbitrarily close together, then you will sometimes get duplicates, that is a mathematical necessity.

Comment: Well I guess it can't be exponential if it should be well rounded. Maybe I should have said non-linear then ;) Anyhow, primary requirement is to have customer-compatible numbers with a growing interval.
My guess was to round the numbers with a more dynamic approach that considers the smaller range, instead of the fixed values I put in.

Comment: can you provide the expected output for the two test cases. 5000-10000 and 100-1000

Comment: Should be something like:
5000-10000: 5000, 5500, 6500, 8000, 10000;
100-1000: 100, 150, 250, 500, 750, 1000

It doesn't have to be exact though.